# Reducing space before and after matrices

Tags: spacing, environments, matrices

I find the extra space added before and after matrices quite ugly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$f\begin{pmatrix}
    1&2\\
    3&4
\end{pmatrix}.$
\end{document}
```

I would like to reduce it. While I am aware that creating a custom matrix environment (e.g., `mymatrix`) with negative space adjustments is a possible solution, this approach causes issues when taking powers of matrices: it misplaces the exponent.

Is there an alternative method or package that allows for reducing the space around matrices without affecting the placement of exponents when taking powers of matrices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `mleftright`, that avoids the additional space around `\left` and `\right`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright

\begin{document}

$f\begin{pmatrix}
    1&2\\
    3&4
\end{pmatrix}.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can add a brace group to remove the mathinner spacing

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$f\begin{pmatrix}
    1&2\\
    3&4
\end{pmatrix}.$


$f{\begin{pmatrix}
    1&2\\
    3&4
\end{pmatrix}}.$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg as it says?